# How do i change Firebase-ui language?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

### How can i change the default language of the firebase-ui login ?

[LanguageLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kcCQ.png)

Answer (score 7):

I achieved firebaseUI translation to my local language by following these steps:

- 1. Clone firebaseui-web repository

```
git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web
```

- 2. Once the repo is cloned, go inside the just created firebaseui-web folder and run:

```
npm install
```

```
npm run build build-js-pt-BR && npm run build build-npm-pt-BR
```

****Note***: In my case I wanted to set firebaseUI to brazilian portuguese, therefore I used the language code **pt-BR** when running 'npm build'. Consequently the generated files will have a **pt_br** suffix.
Just replace this with your desired language code to have firebaseUI working on the language you want. Here you find a list of all supported languages and its codes:
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/LANGUAGES.md

- 3. In the created firebaseui-web/dist/ folder, copy the **"firebaseui__pt_br.js"** and **"npm__pt_br.js"** files and paste them into your project's **node_modules/firebaseui/dist/** folder
- 4. Go to your your project and replace the standard firebaseui import: Instead of importing from firebaseui, refer now to the **firebase/dist/npm__pt_br.js** file you just added into node_modules, like this:

```
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui/dist/npm__pt_br'
```

- 5. That's it! Now you should have firebaseUI configured to our language of choice!

[picture of firebaseUI translated to brazilian portuguese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0O93.png)

More details on these links:

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#building

https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/FirebaseUI-Angular/issues/42

This answer was obtained from https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423285/alterar-idioma-do-template-do-firebaseui. Thanx @Klebers for the having this issue solved!

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#localized-widget):

> Localized versions of the widget are available through the CDN. To use a localized widget, load the localized JS library instead of the default library:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.4.0/firebase-ui-auth__{LANGUAGE_CODE}.js"></script>
> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
> ```
>
> where `{LANGUAGE_CODE}` is replaced by the code of the language you want.

For a longer explanation read the docs on Github linked above.